# Regarding if else multiple conditions

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a constants file `abcder.constants` as shown below

```
public static final String ABC_abbject_EOD = "DDD_Report";
public static final String CDE_abbject_INTRADAY = "FFD_Report";
```

Now I have the below method as shown below

```
public void Gen(String[] toAddress, String[] ccAddress, String abbject,
                String message, String defIdentifier, Date date)
```

Now in this method there can be two cases that is either `defIdentifier` is `null` or `abbject` parameter has a value

1. So if `defIdentifier` is null then `abbject` has a value which is coming from a `abcderconstant` so in that case I  have to do something. That is depending upon the value of the abject it can be `ABC_abbject_EOD` or `CDE_abbject_INTRADAY`
2. If `defIdentifier` is not null then `abbject` is null then in that case I have to perform some other thing

So, I have developed the code as shown below please advise is this correct way

```
if (defIdentifier != null && abbject== null)
{
    String s = defIdentifier + "-" + formatter.format(now.getTime()) + "." + "doc";
}

if (defIdentifier == null && abbject.equalsIgnoreCase(abcderconstants.ABC_abbject_EOD))
{
    String s = "DDD-Report" + "-" + formatter.format(now.getTime()) + "." + "doc";
}
if (defIdentifier == null && abbject.equalsIgnoreCase(abcderconstants.CDE_abbject_INTRADAY))
{
    String s = "FFD-Report" + "-" + formatter.format(now.getTime()) + "." + "doc";
}
```

Comment: What do any of these names mean? "abbject"? What's this code supposed to do?

Comment: well the issue is to check the conditions forgot the name

Comment: You can't have spaces in variable names

Comment: @Madcore yeah will take care but please advise for the conditions

Comment: @pstanton def identifier is a string variable that contains some value my cause of worry is the conditions logic in if else is it correct please advise and the way I am checking string with ignore case please aevise

Comment: shouldn't this question be asked in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if (defIdentifier != null && abbject == null) {
    sb.append(defIdentifier);
} else if (defIdentifier == null && abbject != null ) {

    if(abbject.equalsIgnoreCase(abcderconstants.ABC_abbject_EOD)) {
         sb.append("DDD-Report");
    } else if (abbject.equalsIgnoreCase(abcderconstants.CDE_abbject_INTRADAY)) {
         sb.append("FFD-Report");
    } else {
         // throw invalid abbject type exception?
    }

} else {
    // both defIdentifier and abbject are either null or not null. Illegal args?
}

sb.append("-" + formatter.format(now.getTime()) + "." + "doc");
String s = sb.toString();
```

Comment: I'd say `sb.append("-").append(formatter.format(now.getTime())).append(".doc");` :)

Answer (score 0):

Put `String s = ...` outside the if statements. It may be a good idea to check if `abbject` is null. Please try to use better variable names.

```
String s = null;

if (defIdentifier != null && abbject == null) {
    s = defIdentifier + "-" + formatter.format(now.getTime()) + "." + "doc";
} 
else if (defIdentifier == null && abbject != null && abbject.equalsIgnoreCase(abcderconstants.ABC_abbject_EOD)) {
    s = "DDD-Report" + "-" + formatter.format(now.getTime()) + "." + "doc";
}
else if (defIdentifier == null && abbject != null && abbject.equalsIgnoreCase(abcderconstants.CDE_abbject_INTRADAY)) {
    s = "FFD-Report" + "-" + formatter.format(now.getTime()) + "." + "doc";
}
```